# Why are first few string assignments slower?

Tags: c, string, performance, initialization

I have been measuring the speed of initializing strings with the following code and found something odd:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define START_COUNTING  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start)
#define END_COUNTING    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end)
#define NUM_OF_LOOPS    8192

long time_difference(struct timespec end, struct timespec beginning) {
    long long diff = (long long)end.tv_sec - (long long)beginning.tv_sec;
    return(end.tv_nsec - beginning.tv_nsec + ((diff > 0) ? 1000000L : 0));
}

long average(long numbers[NUM_OF_LOOPS]) {
    long long sum = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_LOOPS; i++)
        sum += numbers[i];

    return sum / NUM_OF_LOOPS;
}

int main(void) {
    struct timespec start;
    struct timespec end;
    long time_diffs[NUM_OF_LOOPS];
    int i;
    char * str = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_LOOPS; i++) {
        START_COUNTING;
        str = "T";
        END_COUNTING;
        time_diffs[i] = time_difference(end, start);
    }
    printf("%li ns - assigning 2 chars to a string\n", average(time_diffs));

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_LOOPS; i++) {
        START_COUNTING;
        str = "Testing";
        END_COUNTING;
        time_diffs[i] = time_difference(end, start);
    }
    printf("%li ns - assigning 8 chars to a string\n", average(time_diffs));

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_LOOPS; i++) {
        START_COUNTING;
        str = "Testing it here";
        END_COUNTING;
        time_diffs[i] = time_difference(end, start);
    }
    printf("%li ns - assigning 16 chars to a string\n", average(time_diffs));

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_LOOPS; i++) {
        START_COUNTING;
        str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit nullam.";
        END_COUNTING;
        time_diffs[i] = time_difference(end, start);
    }
    printf("%li ns - assigning 64 chars to a string\n", average(time_diffs));

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_LOOPS; i++) {
        START_COUNTING;
        str = ""; // String omitted because it would waste a lot of space
        END_COUNTING;
        time_diffs[i] = time_difference(end, start);
    }
    printf("%li ns - assigning 1024 chars to a string\n", average(time_diffs));

    return 0;
}
```

when profiling it I always come up with this result:

```
1126 ns - assigning 2 chars to a string
828 ns - assigning 8 chars to a string
832 ns - assigning 16 chars to a string
834 ns - assigning 64 chars to a string
857 ns - assigning 1024 chars to a string
```

The first result no matter if it's assigning 2 chars, 8 chars or however many is always significantly slower than the rest. I have tried putting 1 assignment before the loops, but it still didn't change the results much.

Does anyone know why the first few times one assigns into strings is slower? I have looked around, but only found an answer that happened due to a JIT compiler, but C doesn't use those.

Comment: CPU caching maybe? On-demand loading of the data?

Comment: Number of characters doesn't matter - in any case it just assigns a pointer. First execution of a function may be slower, because required data should be loaded to the memory.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't actually copy any character data, since you're just setting a pointer to a string literal.

Thus, the entire premise is wrong, and there is no correlation between the number of characters "assigned" and the time taken.

This is a super-micro-benchmark, and very very hard to get right since you're essentially trying to measure the time taken for a single pointer-size assignment, which is really not a lot of code.

The difference in speed might be caused by cache/memory latency. You can read the generated code to figure out if `str` is stored in a register or not, and of course also play with the optimization settings.

Note: your measurement method, averaging, means that the cache footprint of the overhead (the `time_diffs` array) is *much* larger than that of the test itself, so that's probably what's causing the irregularity, the first time `time_diffs` isn't cached.

Comment: I never said that my code copies any data. How is this relevant?

Comment: @TheRedFox You said "no matter if it's assigning 2 chars, 8 chars or however many".

Answer (score 0):

There are two important items here:-

- Don't use debug code for timing things
- Make sure you're actually timing something

The first is obvious, the second is not so. For example, this code:-

```
for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_LOOPS; i++) {
    START_COUNTING;
    str = "T";
    END_COUNTING;
    time_diffs[i] = time_difference(end, start);
}
```

is quite likely to be compiled to this by an optimising compiler:-

```
for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_LOOPS; i++) {
    START_COUNTING;
    END_COUNTING;
    time_diffs[i] = time_difference(end, start);
}
str = "T";
```

The reason for the first loop being slow, probably caching. The cpu has to load the code from RAM/HD and that takes a while, especially as you have a function call in there. Try putting this before the timing loops:-

```
    START_COUNTING;
    END_COUNTING;
```

and hopefully the code is brought into cache ready for the timing loops.